# Bash for each/if alternate letters and numbers

Tags: bash

Hoping to find other ideas on how to make this kind of thing happen.. I've got a small project of generating a string with a combination of characters and digits. This is to help speed things up for submitting documentation to the FDA (hence it being **very** picky in terms of it's formatting).

I've got some sample data from the FDA (listed below and changed for public viewability). The problem I'm having is alternating between letters and digits for the last character, the rest is cake. Anyone got any ideas? Maybe even another language if it'll be easier..

```
TP1A1AAA1
TP2B2BBB2
TP3C3CCC3
TP4B4SFFB
TP5B5SFFC
TP6B4SFFD



count=100
i=0

 for lone in {F..T}; do
    for ltwo in {D..Z}; do
            for lthree in {A..Z}; do
                    let "i++"               # Counter for limiting the loops
                    if [[ $i == $count ]]
                    then
                            # Limit the amount of times this will loop
                            exit
                    else
                            # Need for loop and if statement for switching between numbers and letters.
                            # Return results
                            echo "TP9B4S$lone$ltwo$lthree"
                    fi
            done
    done
 done
```

Comment: not clear if you expect to use the full range of `(0?)[1-9]` and `[A-Z]` ? If just a list like `1,2,3,B,C,D` then code that correct level in a `for` loop, i.e. `for lastDig in 1 2 3 B C D ; do echo $line${lastDig} ; done` ? It will help all readers if you add these sort of details to your Q, rather than engage in back and forth in comments (as most people seem to do ;-/ (not you maybe!) ). AND show your current code and current output. That's probably why you have a downvote (I didn't downvote). Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, yes.. full range, A-Z 0-9.. Also.. My current code is just 2 different for loops for the first 2 patterns and the 4 sits in a if statement.

Comment: update your Q with your requirements. We should be able to delete all of these comments, if you have a well constructed Q. Glad you put the code in, can you indent properly and remove blank lines please? I'm going to bed, hopefully others can help out or I'll check in the morning. GOod luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reformatting. To get A-Z followed by 0-9 try changing your line:

```
for lthree in {A..Z}; do
```

to:

```
for lthree in {{A..Z},{0..9}}; do
```